# EEPROM size limitation issue

Tags: arduino-nano, eeprom

I am creating a test program with Arduino Nano where I can save network and password. Here is my code to start with:

```
void SaveNetwork(String ssid, String pass){
  String com = ssid + "~" + pass;
  const char *array = com.c_str();
  for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(com); i++){
    EEPROM.write(i, array[i]);
  }
  Serial.println("Saved");
  char ar[255] = "";  //test read string.
  for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(com); i++){
    ar[i] = EEPROM.read(i);
  }
  Serial.println(ar);
}

SaveNetwork("Testing", "Network123......");
```

Now I print ar string which is suppose to return ssid, "~" and password.

BUT what I get is "Testin" instead of "Testing~Network123......".

Is there is a limitation for EEPROM size? If so, how can I expand the capacity, should I use a memory chip, or what is the code I should use to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `sizeof(com)` in your loops. `sizeof()` is for C arrays, not string objects. If you print it, it will report 6, which is not the length of the array. For string objects you should use `com.length()` instead. Then the output becomes

> Saved
>
> Testing~Network123......

P.S. The EEPROM can store 1024 bytes on ATmega328P-based boards (I believe that's what most Arduino Nanos use (clones included).